# How can I add System.Web.Request and System.Web.Response references in ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was manually porting my application from ASP.NET MVC 5 to 6 (ASP.NET 5) and it uses the DNX and the .NET Core. I was using `Request.UserHostAddress` and `Request.UserAgent` in my controllers, but I couldn't add the `System.Web` as a reference to the project.

How can I use Request and Response classes in ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6)?

Comment: Have you tried Request.Headers["User-Agent"]

Answer (score 0):

If your controller derive from `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller` you can access to `HttpContext`, `Request` and `Response` properties.

this sample will help you to access to replacements of `UserHostAddress` and `UserAgent`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        var address = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress; // Request.UserHostAddress
        var userAgent = Request.Headers["User-Agent"].FirstOrDefault(); // Request.UserAgent

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the FirstOrDefault()